# Evernote: Unable to Generate a Temporary Token

Tags: oauth, evernote

I am trying to use `OAuth1` with the `evernote api` following the documentation: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php.
However, whenever I try to generate a temporary token, I am greeted with:

> Oops, we encountered an error.

I am using the following oauth library: https://github.com/sirikata/liboauthcpp
and all I did was modify the demo/simple_auth.cpp with the following:

```
std::string consumer_key = ""; // Key from evernote
std::string consumer_secret = ""; // Secret from evernote
std::string request_token_url = "https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth";
std::string request_token_query_args = "oauth_callback=oob";
std::string authorize_url = "https://sandbox.evernote.com/OAuth.action";
std::string access_token_url = "https://sandbox.evernote.com/oauth";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote OAuth is not supporting the out-of-band (oob) validation. Please try it with a valid callback URL.